# DXF location loading error on QGIS 3.14

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, dxf

I am working in a project that involves data from different files types, I managed to load TIFF and .Gz file (ordinance survey mastermap topography) to correct location. However I have a DXF layer that also needs to be overlayed but when I import it, the location is nowhere near the other two layers. As far as I can tell all my CRS settings are correct.  Does anyone have any ideas what I can do to fix this issue?

Comment: Open the dxf in any CAD software and check the distances from zero. Based on this, choose the correct CRS to load the data. CAD doesn't know CRS specifications, you manually have to make sure you are working in the correct location.

Comment: Unfortunately I've not got access to autocad, doesn't help that I have very little experience with autocad. We're being forced to jerry rig something as a possible client won't give us access to their gis system, they aren't even providing us with the correct shapefiles.

Comment: Then tell them that based on this data you can't "jerry rig" a decent product/prototype. Alternatively you could try to determine the correct CRS of said dxf by loading it into a blank project, zooming to it and checking which coordinates are returned at the bottom of your map window.

Comment: So you're saying that i could load the tiff and. Gz files to location of dxf rather than the other way around?

Comment: No, you don't load anything to a location, the data itself knows where it is. The dxf simply doesn't tell QGIS which CRS it is in, and you need to find out, which it is, so you may set the correct one.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking stupid questions, been thrown for a loop by this client and now pulling my hair out trying to work on news systems.  How do i get the crs from coordinates?

Comment: By comparing. Obviously it isn't in the same CRS as the other data, or it would be displayed in the same location. So you need to get some coordinates, and then you have to check, which CRS might fit. Obviously, decimal degree are easy to distinguish from other CRS. Best course of action would be to let someone who is proficient with GIS take a look.